# All Permutations of a string when corresponding characters are not in the same place

Tags: c++, c, string, algorithm, permutation

I need all possible permutations of a given string such that no character should remain at the same place as in the input string.
Eg. : for input "ask"
Output: all possible permutaions like "ksa", "kas"... 
such that 'a' is not in the 1st position , 's' is not in the 2nd positions and so on... in any permutation.

**I only need the count of such possible permutations**

I can do this by generating all permutations and filtering them but I need a **very efficient** way of doing this.

All characters in the string are "UNIQUE"

Preferred language C++.

Comment: You should probably post the way you've come up with first. We can go on from there.

Comment: no all the characters in the string are UNIQUE

Comment: @noko I have already done it using the less efficient way : finding all possible permutations and filtering them

Comment: That's not **so** inefficient, you know. The number of derangements (fixed-point-free permutations) of `n` symbols is asymptotically `n!/e`, so creating all and filtering is just a constant factor from optimal.

Comment: You should still post your code first, we need to know what you've tried first. Also is this homework?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Calculating the faculty n! takes n multiplications (O(n)), creating all permutations takes (O(n!)), filtering a word has a worst-case complexity of O(n). Filtering all possible permutations takes (O(n! * n)). Whelp. Better just calculate `!n = n!  \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i/i!`, which can be done in O(n*n) (maybe even faster) if the interim results are saved.

Comment: @Zeta Oops, I overlooked that the OP only needs the count. I thought the permutations themselves were wanted.

Comment: @DanielFischer so if I need only the count, I should only calculate: !n = n! \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i/i!???

Comment: Soo.. the result could be derived solely from length of the input string?  There is only one solution for any string of length X?  There should be an analytical solution for this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: @Ivan Vergiliev: I've just found the same thing by searching for the sequence. http://oeis.org/search?q=+1%2C+2%2C+9%2C+44%2C+265%2C+1854%2C+14833 . post it as an answer

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is called a derangement - the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) has a good explanation of one approach to get the formula, as well as a couple of different equations for the result.

You can also calculate the number using the inclusion-principle, starting with the number of all permutations - n!, then subtracting the permutations with one number fixed on its place, adding the permutations with two numbers fixed, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

For a set of `n` distinguishable elements you can arrange them with no element being at its original position in `dearangements(n)` ways:

```
int derangements(int n) {
    assert(n >= 0);
    return n ? ((n - 1) * (derangements(n - 1) + derangements(n - 2)) : 1;
}
```

Note that this has an exponential runtime due to non-linear recursion. You can however improve this formula.

```
int derangements(int n) {
    assert(n >= 0);
    if(n == 0) return 1;

    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;
    do {
       int x = (n-1)*(a+b);
       a = b;
       b = x;
    } while(--n > 1);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Really classy - try a number of wrong answers first, then look up the term from another answer and post an (exponential) implementation... :)

Comment: and it's still wrong, first one with `derangements(1)`, and the second one has a bug

Comment: Now it should be correct. @IvanVergiliev It only was one wrong answer.